# template to match <a>tag followed by <img>tag

Tags: xslt

I want to write xslt template to match a Tag followed by img tag.

Sample valid source:

```
1.<a title="google site" href="http://google.com"><img style="width: 141px; height: 167px;" alt="Image" title="Image" src="tcm:202-11587"/></a>
2.<a title="Internal link" href="tcm:202-9720"><img style="width: 141px; height: 167px;" alt="Image" title="Image" src="tcm:202-11587"/></a>
```

Invalid:

```
1.<a title="google site" href="http://google.com"></a>
  <img style="width: 141px; height: 167px;" alt="Image" title="Image" src="tcm:202-11587"/>

2.<img style="width: 141px; height: 167px;" alt="Image" title="Image" src="tcm:202-11587"/>
 <a title="google site" href="http://google.com"></a>

3.<a title="google site" href="http://google.com"><img style="width: 141px; height: 167px;" alt="Image" title="Image" src="tcm:202-11587"/></a>
  <a title="Internal link" href="tcm:202-9720"><img style="width: 141px; height: 167px;" alt="Image" title="Image" src="tcm:202-11587"/></a>

4.<a><img/></a>
```

Rules:

```
1.Only one Image should be allowed and it should be hyperlink.
2.There should be one <img> tag wrapped by one <a> tag.
3. Multiple images are not allowed.
4.Attributes for Image and a Tag.
5.No text is allowed for both the tags.
```

Can any help how to write template to match this condition.

Comment: what you want to do with that tag?

Comment: @infantprogrammer'Aravind'. I want to check for soemcondition if such occurance is encountered.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that XSLT templates don't match tags, they match elements. The start tag for the a element is immediately followed by the start tag for the img element, but from an XSLT point of view the structure you are looking for is an a element that has an img element as its only child.

Your fourth rule "Attributes for Image and a Tag." is incomplete: you haven't said what condition the attributes of the two elements must satisfy.

You also haven't made it clear whether you want your template rule to match the img element or the a element.

Here's a rule that matches the img element provided the containing a element has an href attribute:

```
match="a[@href]/img[not(preceding-sibling::node() or following-sibling::node())]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this xpath in your `match` attribute for your template:

```
//a[count(@*)>0 and img[count(@*)>0] and count(.//*)=1 and normalize-space(.)='']
```

This selects all `a` elements which have no non-significant text content, attributes, and a single `img` element with attributes.